# How to set a queue producer timeout?

Tags: java, timeout, jms, weblogic, failover

I am testing WebLogic 10.3.1 JMS, but there has a problem.

My Testing step:

1. Start WebLogic Server
2. Start JMS Client
3. Client send a object to WebLogic JMS and server received the object.
4. Stop WebLogic Server
5. Send another object to WebLogic JMS.

What I expect is a exception come out, but there have not anything appear and program hanged. Program stopped at:

```
sender.send(objMsg);
```

I have add some timeout settings, but still not working:

```
((WLProducerImpl) sender).setSendTimeout(1000);
((WLConnection) connection).setReconnectPolicy(JMSConstants.RECONNECT_POLICY_PRODUCER);
((WLConnection) connection).setReconnectBlockingMillis(1000);
```

Is there any way to produce exception in this case? Thank You Very Much.

Best Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Found:

Please add these 2 parameters:

```
-Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=30000
-Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=30000
```

Comment: This did not at all change any behavior. I expect a call to send to somehow throw an exception if it cannot succeed in sending - this does not happen. My mqjms.log files run full of stupid messages, but my code does not see any exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting timeout in send method. something similar to following:
sender.send(objMsg, Message.DEFAULT_DELIVERY_MODE, Message.DEFAULT_PRIORITY, 10000);

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the WebLogic transport is hung and hasn't detected the server has gone - and the send is blocked in the transport. Unless WebLogic JMS are using a separate thread internally, there's no a timeout will help.

IMHO, WebLogic support are the only guys who'll be able to help you on this one (looks like a bug).