# jms create connection http timeout - weblogic

Tags: java, spring, jms, weblogic, spring-jms

Is there a way to specify a JMS HTTP Connection timeout for a WebLogic JMS producer?

I am asking this because I use Weblogic JMS with Spring JMS Template to send messages to a queue and I have the following scenario:

1. JMS server is up
2. I start the producer app and it is able to send messages to the queue
3. I stop the JMS server
4. The app tries to send a message to the queue, but it gets a ConnectionRefused exception after about 1 minute and 30 seconds

So I guess this timeout is actually the default http connection timeout at JVM level and I wouldn't want to set the below properties:

```
-Dsun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout=30000
-Dsun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout=30000
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a queue producer timeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872894/how-to-set-a-queue-producer-timeout)

Comment: I know, but I explicitly mentioned that the solution for that question does not apply to my issue.